# Reading DAT File

Tags: python

I'm working with the following code to have it print the contents of contact.dat, however I get an error.

```
import pickle
def main():

    infile = open("contacts.dat",'wb')
    file_contents = infile.read()
    infile.close()
    print(file_contents)

main()



File "C:\Python31\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 36: character maps to <undefined>
```

How can I get the code to read and print the file?

Comment: Can you put the whole traceback?

Comment: Also, why are you openning the file in write mode and then reading it? You should be getting `UnsupportedOperation` error, not `UnicodeDecode`

Comment: What's in `contacts.dat` and what type of file is that? Is it a binary or text file? Could it be a pickled file (since you `import pickle`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shot in the dark, but I usually use readlines, along with 'with open..':

```
with open("contacts.dat") as infile:
    file_contents = infile.readlines()
print(file_contents)
```

Try that?

Comment: it takes lots of memory when using the method for the binary case